# How to make bar plot below leaflet map in same tab in shinyapp

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am new to shiny-app. I have a few experience of using R for data analysis. I want to create a bar plot below the leaflet map with some space between two maps. when i write code then it shows error "non-numeric argument to binary operator"
leaflet map will be displayed correctly. But bar plot couldn't show. How i fix that. Bar plot was between two thing 
first on x-axis is names of districts
on y-axis there values in numeric.

Comment: Can you share the code you have written, that way we can better understand your problem

Comment: @SymbolixAU thanks. my problem has been solved. Now I have an other problem. That i want to draw multiple leaf let map on multiple tabs in shiny app with single data set and then i want to download all maps with single download button??